# MvvmCross Resize UITableView once binded

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have a MvxTableViewSource which is bound to my TableView, I want the TableView's frame height to match it's content height. The below code doesn't do anything visual to my app even though the TableView's height has been updated (at breakpoint in ViewDidAppear),  the TableView's height display to what was set initially in ViewDidLoad.

Any ideas of how I can programmatically set the frame height of the binded TableView so it shows on screen, the value seems to be set correctly but the UI is not being updated?

```
public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
{
        base.ViewDidAppear(animated);

        var frame = _jobTable.Frame;
        frame.Height = _jobTable.ContentSize.Height;
        frame.Width = View.Frame.Width;
        _jobTable.Frame = frame;
        _jobTable.SetNeedsDisplay();
}
```